# ASP.Net MVC Razor Document Downloading as Corrupt

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an ASP.Net project that is based off of Razor. We are posting documents from the client side using formdata and need to change the name of this file based on who is uploading it. We have a method for doing so, which you can see here:

```js
var fileToSave = "";

if (filename != null) {
    fileToSave = '@ViewBag.CompName' + "-" + filename.name;
    fileToSave = fileToSave.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Document", filename, fileToSave);
```

This saves the document with the proper name, e.g. "Test-Company-test.docx"

The problem exists when I go to download the file and open it up. The document downloads properly, and has the appropriate size of the uploaded file, for this purpose, "test.docx".

When opening the downloaded file, Word prompts you with the following:

[image: We're sorry. We can't open the document because we found a problem with its contents.]

Pressing "OK" then shows the following message:
[image: Word found unreadable content in this document. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes.]

Following this message, if you click "Yes," the document opens and the entirety of the document is there. There is no corrupt data, and everything is formatted exactly how it is supposed to be.

This error does not exist if we just save the document as the original document name. Which normally we would do, but this is a large application that is client facing and allows users to upload documents themselves. This can be a problem if Company A uploads a document called "Test.docx" and Company B also uploads a document called "Test.docx" thus overwriting Company A's document. Hence, the renaming of the documents.

How is it that we can prevent this error from happening?

Comment: What do the details of the error say?

Comment: @I.R.R. "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened."

Comment: Typically you save the document to a file server containing a `Guid` and the files extension as the file name (and save that path plus the files name (for display purposes) in the db.  Alternatively you can also create separate folders for each company (but there is still a risk that a company might upload multiple files with the same file name)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've handled that as well. On our database side, we store the filename that is "fileToSave". Then saved in a folder dependent on what is being uploaded. If it is a company level, location level, material level, or location material level.

EDIT: (Accidentally pressed enter)

`var fileToSave = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Document"];
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Documents/MaterialDocs"), fileToSave.FileName);
                    fileToSave.SaveAs(path);
return "success";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to answer this question. It turns out that I had forgotten to add the filesize to the download information, so when it was downloading it didn't know how large the file was supposed to be. We just had to add the following line of code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
```

So to close everything together, this is what the download function looked like at the end:

```
    public void DownloadCompanyDoc(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var getFile = rep.GetCompanyDocById(id);
            var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Documents/CompanyDocs"), getFile);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();

                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + getFile);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
                Response.WriteFile(path);
                Response.TransmitFile(path);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future (pending someone else ever experiences this).

Comment: This had been a lifesaver for me today (using IHttpActionResults with Web API v2).